# msvcr90d.dll not found when debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll

Sometimes microsoft make me feel dizzy. When I try to debug my project, VS throws a message box with this error: **msvcr90d.dll not found, and reintalling the software may solve this error**. But in the results window, while loading simbols, this line appear:

```
'GLFW_Window.exe': loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_bb1f6aa1308c35eb\msvcr90d.dll', Loaded symbols.
```

If I go to this folder, the DLL actually exists. Also, I have tried to download previous versions of the same projects that has been work correctly an still fails. Could a uninstallation delete this dlls? (It is not a clean machine but my personal machine).

By the way, if I copy manually the DLLs of this folder to my project, I get a weird error about make a manifest.

Could any of you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This could be a lot of things, trying to get the manifest file right might fix it. I would also check out my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550896/loadlibrary-module-not-found-dll-hell-after-office-2007-install which was just the dll not being on the right path.

Comment: After checking your message, I have passed dependency walker an it confirmed that this DLL isn't in the right place (at least it is not in path). But what has changed this path? Not me!!

Comment: Since you've yet to accept Hans's answer, are you still convinced that what you're getting is an error? Why do you read "loaded symbols" (you *do* have to scroll all the way over to the right) as an error? Is there another message that you haven't shown us in your question?

Comment: Yes, I'm convinced. I do not accepted the Hans's answer. The error is: having loaded the sysmbols, just after application starts, why appears a message box saying that I need to reinstall application because this dll wasn't found? Dependency walker confirm that this dll isn't found. I don't understand how to solve this

Comment: Try turning off incremental linking and see if that fixes your problem. Otherwise, can you tell us more about your configuration? Is your solution stored on a removable drive? Are any of your drives formatted as FAT32? Etc.

Comment: Nothing about that. NTFS on all drives and is a normal project installed in C:. Could be the way a code is writen that affects msvcr90d.dll?

Answer (score 6):

Notice the complete absence of the word "error".  It is not an error, just a notification from the debugger that a DLL got loaded.  Do *not* mess with the file, you'll break Visual Studio.

If you don't want to see the message then right-click the Output window and untick "Load messages".

Comment: Mmmm, not really. Dll hasn't been not found. This is an error. With the message I want to add some more details (understanding that is not an error, it is simply the output of the debug).

Comment: It says "loaded", it doesn't say "file not found".  "Loaded" is the opposite of not finding a file.

Comment: And this is my question!!! First, when program starts, into visual studio window "results" it seems that dll has been loaded. Then window seems to start and a messagebox says that this dll hasn't been found and that reinstalling program may solve the problem.

Comment: You are not asking this question the Smart Way.  Tell us what the message box says, we need something that says "Error".  Make a screen shot.  Also look in the Windows Event log for an error message.  Post everything you know in your question.