# How to deploy a WPF app using ribbon controls library?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

I created a WPF application (c#/XAML) under Visual Studio 2012(Upgrade 4) using Ribbon Controls Library under .NET 4.0 Win7 32 bits.
It works fine, but I can't make it work under a Win XP 32 bits host.

I installed :
- .NET 3.5 SP1
- .NET 4.0
- Ribbon for WPF, found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877) (the same is installed on the machine on which I made the app of course)

But it fails as I add the ribbon to the app.
I tried to manually add the RibbonControlsLibrary.dll, with no more success.

Here's the log of snoop :

```
Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Stacktrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at AppliErgos.MainWindow.InitializeComponent()
   at AppliErgos.MainWindow..ctor()
   at AppliErgos.LogWindow.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)


InnerException:

Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Stacktrace:
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveAssembly(BamlAssembly bamlAssembly)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlTypeToType(BamlType bamlType)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType(BamlType bamlType, Int16 typeId)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetXamlType(Int16 typeId)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_ElementStart()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_OneBamlRecord()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_BamlRecords()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Read()
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
```

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved ! ***System***.Windows.Controls.Ribbon appeared to be from .NET4.0 ... but installed only if you install .NET4.5 !?!?!?!?!?
We simply have to point ***Microsoft***.Windows.Controls.Ribbon
Weird :-\

Answer (score 0):

You can start with "Dependency walker" (depends.exe) utility by SysInternals. It's quite often that there are indirect references (for instance, your app -> ribbon DLL -> some other missed DLL) which are not reported by name but prevent the app to run properly. Dependency Walker (or other similar tools) would shed more light on entire tree of used modules (still, there may be false alarms, be aware)

Comment: Nice tool. I've installed and runned it. It tells me that 2 dlls are missing (ieshims.dll and wer.dll) but I've read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465111/dependency-walker-reports-ieshims-dll-and-wer-dll-missing) that these dlls are not useful on WinXP and their detection may stop Dependency Walker from completing the tree ... :-\

Comment: I've made it run directily on ribboncontrolslibrary.dll with the same result than on the whole app !

Comment: Well, I tried to install IE7 so that these DLLs wouldn't stop anymore the tree generation of "Dependency Walker" ... but it fails on another DLL (dwmapi.dll) and first clues suggest to ... uninstall IE7 ... lol

Comment: Problem solved ! **System**.Windows.Controls.Ribbon appeared to be from .NET4.0 ... but installed only if you install .NET4.5 !?!?!?!?!? We simply have to point **Microsoft**.Windows.Controls.Ribbon

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting. Did "Dependency walker" show that DLL once you checked for dependency tree?