# Can I call Windows 10 Wifi settings screen without explorer.exe shell?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, settings

I have a custom application running as a the shell (Windows 10 Enterprise) for a particular user - i.e. the user boots straight into this application.

However, I want to be able to provide access to the WiFi settings form. I have read that the way to do this is something like

```
Process.Start("ms-settings:network-wifi");
```

or

```
Process.Start("ms-availablenetworks:");
```

However, as far as I can tell, that relies on explorer running as the shell.

I've tried...

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\explorer.exe";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "ms-availablenetworks:";

proc.Start();
```

All of the above work fine if I run in a normal environment, i.e. with explorer as the shell.

But for this user (with my custom shell application), I get an instance of explorer.exe running and displaying an error, `Class not registered`

I have also come across using `LaunchUriAsync()` but I don't think that would help me here, besides it's only available for Windows Store applications for what I've read, which this is not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498523/process-start-throwing-class-not-registered-exception-in-c-sharp

Comment: @JonasTuemandMøller - Thanks but neither of the answers provided in that question help - It's throwing the error outside of the Visual Studio environment, and I have got wer.dll

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to get this working

First start explorer on its own, then a second `Process.Start()` to run the settings page.

Unfortunately, when `explorer.exe` runs, it displays the taskbar which I don't want. (I had previously assumed I'd be able to hide it with a group policy setting or something but this doesn't appear to be the case).

But I suppose that's another question...