# Missing .DLL files Anaconda 4.1.1 32-bit

Tags: python, dll, anaconda, windows-2003-webserver

I've installed **Anaconda 4.1.1 32-bit** on our **Windows 2003 Server**.

When I try to run a program through the command prompt it gives me the following error message:

```
..\python.exe is not a valid Win32 application
```

After searching around for a bit, I downloaded dependency walker to take a look at what is missing and it looks like **wer.dll** and **ieshims.dll** have a problem opening.

I can't make heads nor tails of this.

Comment: Pictures of text are not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Those .dll files appear to have been removed by IE8. You should be able to restore them by installing Visual C++ 2005 SP1

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=26347
```

Attributed from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23484851/3006366

Comment: If the missing .dll files are what is causing the issue, then it should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question, there's three different types namely  
vcredist_x86.EXE, vcredist_IA64.EXE, and vcredist_x64.EXE. Which one should I install?

Comment: You will need to use `vcredist_x86.EXE` since you are on a 32-bit Windows installation.

Comment: @ThatRiddimGuy If that answered your question, you should mark the answer thusly.